# Search any value like search term in javascript json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

i have json array of objects like this , i display it as html table , above the table , there is a search input yielding search term .

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"title": "my frig closed",
"description": "closed frig pla ola pla",
"point": 8989,
"user_id": 4,
"created_at": "2019-11-23T19:54:46.000Z",
"updated_at": "2019-11-23T19:54:46.000Z",
"deleted_at": null
},
{
"id": 4,
"title": "miu you inc",
"description": "closed frig pla ola pla",
"point": 6767,
"user_id": 6,
"created_at": "2019-11-23T19:58:08.000Z",
"updated_at": "2019-11-23T19:58:08.000Z",
"deleted_at": null
}
]
```

i want to search a table for term from input to any value from inside the above array , then return the object includes the term or substring of that term ..

like if `onChange` i search for `pl` for instance , i want all objects containing that term.

Comment: The tools you need are `filter`, `Object.values`, `some`, `includes`.

Comment: I dont know why downvote , i searched before i apply the question, the vote depend on the user points not for a logic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to retrieve all values and `filter` along with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/some) to detect if string exists as substring ([includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) in any of those values:

```js
const data = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "my frig closed",
    "description": "closed frig pla ola pla",
    "point": 8989,
    "user_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2019-11-23T19:54:46.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-23T19:54:46.000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "miu you inc",
    "description": "closed frig pla ola pla",
    "point": 6767,
    "user_id": 6,
    "created_at": "2019-11-23T19:58:08.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-23T19:58:08.000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}
];

let phrase = "pl";

let result = data.filter(
    obj => Object.values(obj).some(
       val => typeof val === "string" && val.includes(phrase)
    )
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object to hold stuff including the functions to be used, then add a lookup function to that.  This form I used will work even in very old browsers like IE 6 with decent speed. I added a lookup and lookupAny and a couple of examples.

```js
let myObjects = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "my frig closed",
    "description": "closed frig pla ola pla",
    "point": 8989,
    "user_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2019-11-23T19:54:46.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-23T19:54:46.000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "miu you inc",
    "description": "closed frig pla ola pla",
    "point": 6767,
    "user_id": 6,
    "created_at": "2019-11-23T19:58:08.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-23T19:58:08.000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
];

var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.functions = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAny: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      //return this.indexOf(str) !== -1
      if (myArray[i][property].indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
  remove: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first term has to be removed
      }
    }
  },
  removeByIndex: function(myArray, index) {
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
};

// exact
let term = "my frig closed";
let propertyName = "title";
let firstOnly = true;
let weFound = myApp.functions.lookup(myObjects, term, propertyName, firstOnly);
console.log("match:", weFound);
// a partial
let partterm = "pla";
propertyName = "description";
firstOnly = false;
let weFoundPart = myApp.functions.lookupAny(myObjects, partterm, propertyName, firstOnly);
console.log("match Contains:", weFoundPart);
```